# HOw to get the name of the active java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

How do I get the name of the current eclipse project? I'm in plugin eclipse view and I need the project name of the java application.

Could you help me please.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this a programming question or a question asking for how to use eclipse? Do you want to get the name programmatically or just look it up somewhere now?

Comment: Well, I explain more, I have two projects in eclipse: a  C project with  class (named for example hello.c) and a plugin project, My question is when I run my plugin, I need to execute the c application (hello.c) , so how Can I know or get access to the name of my C class??

Comment: I used this function: // returns the Class object associated with this class
      ClassDemo cl = new ClassDemo();
      Class c1Class = cl.getClass();

      // returns the name of the class
      String name = c1Class.getName();
      System.out.println("Class Name = " + name); but the problem is it returns the class name of my plugin project and not my C project!!!

Comment: Can you add more details about your Plugin-Project-setup? Application, type, ... Everything you selected during the creation of your "Product Configuration".